# How to identify the similar words using the word2vec

Tags: nlp, word2vec, sentence-similarity

input: I have a set of words(N) & input sentence

problem statement:
the sentence is dynamic, the user can give any sentence related to one business domain. we have to map the input sentence tokens to the set of words based on the closeness.

for example, we can use different words to ask the same meaning questions, and hard to maintain all the synonyms hence we have a mechanism to find similar words, we can map easily.

```
1) A meeting scheduled by john
2) A meeting organized by john
```

user can frame a sentence in different ways, like the above example.

scheduled & organized are very close.

N set has the word, scheduled. if a user gives a sentence like (2), I have to map the **organized** with **scheduled**.

Comment: What if anything have you tried?

Comment: I didn't try any solution, just figuring out the ways to solve the problem. this is a kind of synonym identification problem. we can use some other approaches to solve the problem apart from word2vec.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "Word Mover's Distance", a way to calculate differences between texts that's essentially based on "bags of word-vectors". It can be expensive to calculate, especially on longer texts, but generally identifies "similar" ranges-of-text better than a simple baseline like "average of all word-vectors".

Beyond that, some of the deeper-neural-network methods of vectorizing text – BERT, ELMo, etc – may do an even-more effective job of placing such "similar intent by different words" texts into close positions in a shared coordinate space.